# Wine not removed after running apt-get purge

Tags: wine, uninstall, purge

I upgraded to Jammy Jellyfish recently and it broke a number of applications and adjustments. I am working on removing/reinstalling them, but Wine is proving difficult.

I ran `sudo apt-get purge wine` and got the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'wine' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`which wine` shows:

```
/usr/bin/wine
```

Is there another removal method I can try?

Comment: How did you originally install Wine?

Comment: [There is no actual file named `/usr/bin/wine`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=wine&mode=exactfilename&suite=jammy&arch=any) so I think this might be a link or now, a broken link. Run the following command: `file /usr/bin/wine` to confirm this.

Comment: I believe the commentator below is correct and it was installed from a ppa. But ppa-purge was unable to locate wine, so I am still working on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There is no actual file named `/usr/bin/wine`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=wine&mode=exactfilename&suite=jammy&arch=any) so I think this might be a link or now, a broken link. Run the following command: `file /usr/bin/wine` to confirm this.

If it is an actual file (not a link) and it was installed through a ppa, there are a few ways to find the offending package.

You can use the `dpkg -l` command to list all installed packages and you can filter the results to only include those matching "wine" like this:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i wine
```

This will return all packages that contain the letters "wine" in the name or description. If a package is listed, uninstall or purge the package.

The other way is to use `apt-file` to locate the package that provides the `/usr/bin/wine` file.

First, install `apt-file` using the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-file
```

Then, update it:

```
sudo apt-file update
```

Finally, search for the offending package:

```
apt-file search "/usr/bin/wine"
```

This should return the package name followed by the path to the file contained in the package.

Comment: Thank you, I am working on purging the packages.

Comment: @Pakxos Also, there also might be a wine prefix in your user's home directory. Purging will not typically remove files from your home directory. It might be a hidden directory and you can delete it if you don't want it.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to remove Wine via the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/action.html) by searching for '*wine*'?

Because the package is not called *wine* as I can see it on my system:

[image: Synaptic Package Manager, searching for 'Wine']

Comment: It's not called as such in your system BECAUSE you installed it from the WineHQ PPA instead of the version already available in the Ubuntu repository and probably for no good reason whatsoever.